Ubuntu Command Line Cheat Sheet 2024
I am looking to download the Ubuntu CLI cheatsheet - 2024 version.
New to Ubuntu and Command Line. Always looking for resources to improve my skills.
After downloading Ubuntu Server 24.04.1 LTS from Ubuntu.com I Scrolled down on the page and saw "Ubuntu CLI cheatsheet". "Learn how to use the command line efficiently and get started with DevOps — from basic file management to LXD virtualisation and Ubuntu Pro."
There was a button to download the sheet. Tried opening it several different ways, but no luck. I couldn't find it on Canonical website. I was able to open the image of the first page, but that was it. The page indicates it is from 2024. I have attached an image of the first page.
Image of Page 1 of "Ubuntu CLI cheatsheet"


After downloading Ubuntu Server 24.04.1 LTS from Ubuntu.com I Scrolled down on the page

Clarification: The page you seem to mean is https://ubuntu.com/download/server/thank-you

Please use the "report a bug on this page" link at the bottom of that page to describe the problem you encountered.

Nevertheless, examining the code of that page shows the 2024 cheat sheet to be available here

The cheat sheet is the one I was looking for, thank you! I will add this to the learning experience. 1) Attention to detail does matter! 2) Look at the code a bit closer for clues. 3) I will report the bug.


Always looking for resources to improve my skills.

https://tldp.org/ > Guides > CTRL+F "Bash"
You will find two comprehensive and very complete guides to work through or even just browse for interesting topics.

Thank you for hipping me to this resource!

Note to downwoters and Delete voters: This isn't an exact answer, but very well within a particular wish expressed in the posting... leave some slack and the information level is kept hightened in/at/on askubuntu.

Sorry, still getting use to this. When I hit the other response that it answered my question, it automatically (or so I thought) down voted your response. I tried to get it back to zero, but no luck. I think you did offer a great resource!! Now I will need to add to my homework of reviewing things to make sure I don't provide negative feedback to see if I can correct my mistake!! Please accept my apologies. Gezz, I see really blew it and somehow gave you a -2!! :(
